# check if value is 0 in php with wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to check a value in wordpress using php. If the value is `0` I want to do something, if not do something else.

When i do the following I get:

```
$value = var_dump(post_exists($id));
echo $value;
//int(1286)
```

and if the post doesn't exist I see the following:

```
$value = var_dump(post_exists($id));
echo $value;
//int(0)
```

In javascript I could do

`if(value === 0){..do something..}`

How can I do the equivalent in php ?

Comment: var_dump returns void...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially the same as JavaScript...

```
if ( post_exists($id) ) { 
    // Do something
}
```

The issue is that you're using `var_dump()` incorrectly (you don't need it here).

Answer (score 0):

`php` and `javascript` `if` syntax is almost same.

```
if($value === 0){..do something..}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution:

```
if ( post_exists($id) ) { 
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```